# ngIf Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript, expression, angular-ng-if

I will explain my problem with a simplified example since my code is quite lengthy.

I want to display a certain div when either one of `isFetching` or `isDownloading` is true.

```
<div *ngIf="(isFetching || isDownloading)">
  My div element is here
</div>
```

In the start of my program both of them are true, so the div should be displayed. Below the div from above, I have other elements which are displayed on the view after `isFetching` is changed to `false`. (`isFetching` is changed to `false` after the fetching from the database has completed.) After `isFetching` is changed to `false` and the elements are rendered, after the last element of these is downloaded (it is an image), I then change `isDownloading` to `false`.

When both `isFetching` and `isDownloading` are false, this is when I want to hide the div element.

However, the code I just explained, gives me this error:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
```

I do not seem to understand why do I get this issue? What is wrong with my logic?  How can I achieve the desired result without getting this error?

**EDIT:**

This code is in the constructor of my class:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  this.username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  this.isFetching = false;
});
```

After `isFetching` is changed to `false`. There are other elements in my .html which get rendered. And then this code is called after the last element (which is an image) of those elements is loaded `(load)="latestElementLoaded()"`.

```
latestElementLoaded(){
   this.isDownloading = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that's responsible for setting both `isFetching` and `isDownloading`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngIf - Expression has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513421/ngif-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

Comment: @user184994, I have added the code which you requested.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17572#issuecomment-364175055) in the official repo might be helpful

Comment: You may want to move that code out of the constructor  and into `ngOnInit`

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira, This was quite useful indeed. Since the problem is with the structure of my .html, could you provide me with an advice on how to restructure my code so it is ` single change detection pass from the top down.` I want to display my div when either one of those `isFetching`or `isDownloading` is `true`. Since I cannot do it with an `||` operator, how should I proceed? Should I create another element which is a duplicate of that div and only have `*ngIf="isDownloading"` attached to it? However, I do not think this is the best workaround.

Comment: did you try @user184994 suggestion? to move it from constructor to ngOnInit?

Comment: @user184994, I have just tried it yes. However, it did not fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider an alternative pattern, using observables, which can streamline your code (AngularFire is worth looking into for that):

```
this.data$ = this.angularFirestore.doc('some/path').valueChanges();
```

That gets your data as an observable (this is just demonstration code--check the actual syntax). Put this in `ngOnInit`, not the constructor. No screwing around with `.once` or snapshots or other boilerplate.

Now, in your template, you can write

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else notFetched">
  Data is {{data | json}}
  <ng-template #notFetched>Data is not fetched yet..wait...</ng-template>
</div>
```

This eliminates the need for `isFetching`-like flags altogether.

With regard to your code:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  this.username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  this.isFetching = false;
});
```

I have no idea how this would work at all, since `this` inside the callback function (`function(snapshot)`) is probably going to be undefined, giving you a run-time error.

I'm no expert on Angular internals, but I suspect what is happening to cause the error you report is the following sequence of events:

1. Component is instantiated and constructor runs.
2. Firebase query kicks off.
3. `ngOnInit` is called and change-detected variables examined. `isFetching` is still true at this point.
4. Angular does more work building the view and what have you.
5. Meanwhile, the Firebase query finishes, and 'isFetching` is set to false.
6. Before finalizing this round of rendering, Angular checks one more time (it does this in test mode) just to make sure nothing has unexpectedly changed. But it has!

This entire problem is caused by putting the firebase query logic in the constructor, as mentioned in a comment. Constructors should be strictly limited to basic initialization. They should not contain business logic, and should definitely not contain asynchronous stuff.