# Uncaught Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

> Uncaught Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf:

I have been trying to get updated value on clicking button after going to several sub pages with in the same component, **YES** and **NO** value does not update(Only on the current page it works), though I can see it  through console log in my method.
Below is my code. and I tried below URL

[ngIf - Expression has changed after it was checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513421/ngif-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked)

```
  constructor(
  ) {

  }
 getAssessBtn1(value: any) {    
    this.assesseeValidation = false;
    if (value == 'Yes') {
      this.showAssessBtn1 = true;
      this.showAssessCondition1 = false;
    } else {
      this.showAssessBtn1 = false;
    }
  }
```

I was trying with ngAfterViewChecked, how can I use the method `getAssessBtn1(value: any)` inside it.

**HTML :**

```
<button data-auto-id="AdultTravellersAssess" *ngIf="showAssessBtn1 
                          class="btn btn-secondary assess-btn custom-theme-group-two"
                          (click)="test()">
                    Access
```

Comment: From where are you calling the method ``getAssessBtn1``?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ChangeDetectionRef` for triggering change detection event right after changing the `showAssessBtn` or `showAssesCondition1`.

```js
// inject the changeDetectionRef into your component with
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectionRef) {}


// in the getAssessBtn1 method trigger change detection
getAssessBtn1(value: any) {
 this.assesseeValidation = false;
 if (value == 'Yes') {
   this.showAssessBtn1 = true;
   this.showAssessCondition1 = false;
 } else {
   this.showAssessBtn1 = false;
 }
 this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

With this approach, angular will not complain about expression changed after value is checked. Because you are re-triggering the change detection event when you set your expression to another value.